# Converting md5sum with python

Tags: python-2.7, md5sum

I know how to find the checksum of a file:

```
    # Print checksum of the file
    file = os.popen("md5sum -t " + indir + "/" + binfile)
    checksum = file.read().split(' ')[0]
    print "Checksum of " + binfile + " is " + checksum
```

However, the checksum is a string with 32 characters.
Now, I want to convert this checksum to a 16 characters string, such that every character will represent 2 chars in the checksum (e.g., "63" will be the ascii character 0x63).
How can I do it?

Comment: Side note: don't use `os.popen`.  It has been deprecated since Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `hashlib`?

When you use a `hashlib`-compatible hash implementation such as `hashlib.md5`, the hash object provides a method `digest()` that does what you want.

Example:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> h = hashlib.md5("something")
>>> h.digest()
'C{\x93\r\xb8K\x80y\xc2\xdd\x80Jq\x93k_'
>>> hextxtdigest = h.hexdigest()
>>> hextxtdigest
'437b930db84b8079c2dd804a71936b5f'
>>> # The next line reinvents the wheel.
>>> whatyouwant = "".join([chr(int(hextxtdigest[x:x + 2], 16)) for x in xrange(0, len(hextxtdigest), 2)])
>>> whatyouwant == h.digest()
True
```

I'd suggest you go with the `digest()` method and avoid reinventing the wheel.

---

Edit:

To use it for building a checksum from a file, you typically do something like (in pseudo-python)

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.md5()
open some file ...
read some bytes from file
h.update(those bytes read)
repeat read-and-update until end of file ...
close file
```

After this, the hash object `h` will be ready for getting the digest you want.  See the standard lib doc ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hashlib.html), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)) for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but your reply with "".join()... worked for me, and h.digest() did not work.

Comment: Maybe digest() did not work because I didn't use the h.update().

Comment: @RanSh If you have trouble with using `hashlib` you can try opening a new question.